# How to make SQL Server 2008 compatible to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I have to run the backup of SQL Server 2000 in SQL Server 2008.

While restoring the database from the `.bak` file, I got the error

> specified cast is invalid

After doing google I feel there is compatibility issue. Therefore I want to make the database compatibile to SQL Server 2000.

And run the below query

```
ALTER DATABASE  DBNAME 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80
```

but nothing help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server (like 2008) down to an **older version** (like 2000) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.

Comment: hi @mark , the backup is sql server 2000 and want to restore it in sql server 2008 . thus i think it should not have this problem . Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Changing the compatibility level will get you closer to SQL 2000 but there were breaking changes (more likely they came in when 2005 did), unfortunately you will need to find where you get things that break and manually fix them.

Ed